# Convert a .mp3 to wav file with mplayer

Tags: command-line, audio, conversion

I've a .mp3 file and need to convert that to an 1 channel 8kHz 8 bit wav file, anyone know how I can do that with mplayer ? If not, any other commandline tools I could use ?

Comment: That might be obvious, but keep in mind that you cannot regain the quality that was lost when it the mp3 compression was applied.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

ffmpeg should do the job. This line will convert to 8kHz 1 channel wav file.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -ar 8000 -ac 1 output.wav
```

http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html#SEC11

I'm not sure about the 8 bits requirement - what are you referring to? It's not the bitrate surely?

Comment: it's the bits-per-sample, analagous to the color depth of a picture.  CDDA-style PCM (std WAV) is 16-bit 44.1kHz stereo; he wants output of 8-bit 8kHz mono.

Comment: 8 bit per sample

Comment: In that case the line should be:
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -ar 8000 -ac 1 -acodec pcm_u8 output.wav

Comment: to convert to WAV (M4A, AAC) file, with attributes A-Law, 8000Hz, 64kbps, mono ?

Answer (score 8):

[lame](http://lame.sourceforge.net/using.php), the command-line WAV to MP3 encoder, can also decode MP3 to WAV with the `--decode` switch.

Comment: As user-friendly tools are concerned, I also like mpg321 for decoding: `mpg321 input.mp3 -w output.wav` When I tried lame, it got the duration (play time) wrong in the output file, whereas with mpg321 it came out correct.

Answer (score 2):

[SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net) can also do this; assuming your SoX is compiled with MP3 support, all you'd need is

```
sox input.mp3 -c 1 -r 8000 -1 output.wav
```

... although you might run into clipping issues, in which case you'd want to play with the `vol` and/or `mixer` effects to decrease the volume of the input channels before the resampling happens.

Without MP3-enabled SoX, use an MP3 decoder to convert your MP3 to WAV first, then the above command becomes:

```
sox input.wav -c 1 -r 8000 -1 output.wav
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mplayer -srate 8000 -vo null -vc null -ao pcm:fast:file="$fn.wav" "$fn"
```

This will also work for extracting the audio track from videos, and any other media file mplayer was configured to handle.